# how to select elements with specific id without using javascript frameworks?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am trying to find the list of elements that matches the specified id format.
like I want to select all the tags with classname **"required"** or select all the tags with id like **myObj[any char]** eg. myObj1, myObj2, myObj3, myObja etc

Comment: fyi. ID's should be unique and can be fetched using `document.getElementById`. So "all the tags with id" should never exist..

Comment: @Charles yes that's true, but he's looking for all elements with an "id" value of the same *pattern*, not exactly the same string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it by iterating over all the elements in the DOM:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; ++i) {
  var element = allElements[i];
  if (/\brequired\b/.test(element.className) || /^myObj?/.test(element.id)) {
    // whatever
  }
}
```

Some smarty person will probably be able to explain how to do this with path selectors; I'm not very familiar with that and also it won't work on old IE versions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[Get elements by class name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('foo bar baz');
```

See [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855960/how-to-select-elements-with-specific-id-without-using-javascript-frameworks/3855992#3855992) for selecting by ID prefix.

That said, you're *really* better off using a library to do all that nasty stuff for you.

Comment: It's true that a framework is a good idea here - at worst, it'll have to do the same sort of iteration over the whole DOM, but a good framework will be able to use more sophisticated techniques in browsers that support them.

Comment: @Pointy - **yes.** For the OP - for example, many libraries (like jQuery, YUI, etc.) will use native, non-standard browser selector API methods when available that are _way_ more efficient, such as Gecko's [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll).